# Does redirecting root folder to subdirectory affect SEO?

Tags: html, redirects, google-search, structured-data

I'm developing a very simple static website for my band (only four pages) and I'm currently struggling with structured data markup.

Right now my website hierarchy looks like this:

- /

  - /home/
  - /music/
  - /photos/
  - /bio/

And in the file /index.html I'm using a javascript in the head to redirect to the home page:

```
<script>
document.location = "home"
</script>
```

No doubt that's working, but I'm not sure it's a good thing.

I'm worried this will affect in a bad way results on google search. Should I place my home page in the root directory or is it ok like this? It's better to exclude the root directory from the sitemap?

Comment: Why not you consider your root domain tamrida.com as homepage. Most of all website use homepage as main/root page, what is the purpose of /home, when you can simply display your content on main domain. Don't you think it's looks better?

Comment: It was just for the sake of keeping folders organized, not a big problem. I actually moved the homepage to the root folder after looking at the code of some major band websites.

Comment: Yeah that's why I said it. Otherwise 301 server side redirection is good choice than JavaScript. For example users and Googlebot will immediately redirect from your domain.com to domain.com/home page.

Comment: "I'm currently struggling with structured data markup" - But your question is nothing to do with "structured data markup"?! "for the sake of keeping folders organized" - ordinarily you can still keep folders organized. URLs and file system structure are two different things.

Comment: I'm sorry if the question was misleading. What I meant to say was that I didn't bother about this 'till I started working with google search console. After a few days my structured data information wasn't showing in the results (I know it will take a while) and I started wondering if my website structure was badly affecting google indexing.

Answer (score 1):

For SEO it is better to do it on a server level and make sure to do a 301 redirect as this is much better for SEO.

Of course I don't know what response code a JS redirect will return.

```
Curl -I domain.com
```

The above will tell you what response code you're getting i.e 200, 301, 302

Comment: Since a JS "redirect" only occurs client-side _after_ the HTTP response is received, the "response code" is whatever HTTP status that came with the initial HTTP response. Usually a 200 OK.